# php search within string for word?

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm using PHP's `preg_match` to help determine the value of a string.
But the code only ever prints 1 or 2.

Why aren't the last two cases of my `if` statement ever matched?

```
$atype = strtolower($userData['user_type']);   // let say data is :: company introducer

if ($atype == "individual introducer" || $atype == "individualintroducer" || 
    (preg_match('/i/',$atype) AND preg_match('/int/',$atype)) ) {

       $atype = 1 ;

} elseif ($atype == "individual investor" || $atype == "individualinvestor" ||         
          (preg_match('/i/',$atype) AND preg_match('/inv/',$atype)) ) {

       $atype = 2;

} elseif ($atype == "company introducer" || $atype == "companyintroducer" || 
          (preg_match('/c/',$atype) AND preg_match('/int/',$atype)) ){

       $atype = 3;

} elseif ($atype == "company investor" || $atype == "companyinvestor" || 
          (preg_match('/c/',$atype) AND preg_match('/inv/',$atype)) ){

       $atype = 4;

}

echo $atype;
```

Comment: because "company introducer" matches your second case preg_match and  "company investor" matches the first case preg_match - basically case 3 and 4 are unreachable code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explain your question in a better way.

But i guess as you say the data assumed is `company introducer`.

So it already matches condition for the first if block.
For ex:

In company introducer
The preg_match will return true.

```
if($atype == "individual introducer" || $atype == "individualintroducer" || (preg_match('/i/',$atype) AND preg_match('/int/',$atype))  ){
    $atype =1 ;
}
```

Comment: k got it ... i was checking for first occurrence my bad i not use preg_match correctly